# How to achieve specific RecyclerView ItemDecoration

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

How can I achieve a **RecyclerView** with such **ItemDecoration** as shown below:

Before scrolling:

[image: Before Scrolling]

Then, after scrolling the last item connects to the next/following item:

[image: After]

Comment: What had you tried so far? Or is this just a code request?(which doesn't fit SO)

Comment: I am a beginner so i don't even know where to start i actually stopped at creating and populating the recyclerview.

Answer (score 0):

In your case I would say what you call your "decoration" is actually an item (of another type) you need to populate your `RecyclerView` with.

But you could maybe achieve it with a custom `RecyclerView.ItemDecoration`. You can override `getItemOffsets` & `onDraw`.

- `getItemOffsets` will set the space you need to draw in.
- `onDraw` will decorate the space as you need.

Have a look at [this article](https://medium.com/@nicolas.duponchel/custom-itemdecoration-3b244de437d9) to understand more about building your custom `ItemDecoration`.